# Get the color value for a Google line chart?

Tags: google-visualization

It's possible to set the color values for a Google chart, but is it possible to get the preset color values for a chart? Is there an array that holds those values, that can be accessed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From this Google Groups Discussion the default color array is not documented and cannot be accessed. However, if you want the array of colors, [Xavier Gumara](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-visualization-api/ePpJQEeUX8M) posted it, as did [asgallant](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-visualization-api/fmZzdKnmQC0):

`{"#3366cc","#dc3912","#ff9900","#109618","#990099","#0099c6","#dd4477","#66aa00","#b82e2e","#316395","#994499","#22aa99","#aaaa11","#6633cc","#e67300","#8b0707","#651067","#329262","#5574a6","#3b3eac","#b77322","#16d620","#b91383","#f4359e","#9c5935","#a9c413","#2a778d","#668d1c","#bea413","#0c5922","#743411"}`

Just an FYI, a large portion of these sorts of questions have been covered on the Google Groups by folks like asgallant, and it can be worthwhile to do a quick search to try to find them (quicker than waiting for me to do it!). The above answer was the first two results for 'google visualization default colors'.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the color set was static. I thought the colors were dynamically generated by the number of lines drawn (to add more visual differentiation). Thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: No problem. I have no idea if this is actually the way it works, but since smarter people than I say it's so, I figure it's probably right. You can always create a chart with 32 series and see if they match!